# MongoDB, Panache, Quarkus: How to do aggregate, $sum and filter

Tags: mongodb, sum, aggregate, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have a table in mongodb with sales transactions each containing a userId, a timestamp and a corresponding revenue value of the specific sales transaction.

Now, I would like to query these users and getting the minimum, maximum, sum and average of all transactions of all users. There should only be transactions between two given timestamps and it should only include users, whose sum of revenue is greater than a specified value.

I have composed the corresponding query in mongosh:

```
db.salestransactions.aggregate(
        {
            "$match": { 
                "timestamp": {
                        "$gte": new ISODate("2020-01-01T19:28:38.000Z"),
                        "$lte": new ISODate("2020-03-01T19:28:38.000Z")
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            $group: { 
                _id: { userId: "$userId" }, 
                minimum: {$min: "$revenue"},
                maximum: {$max: "$revenue"},
                sum: {$sum: "$revenue"},
                avg: {$avg: "$revenue"}
            }
        },
         { 
            $match: { "sum": { $gt: 10 } }
         }
    ]
)
```

This query works absolutely fine.

How do I implement this query in a PanacheMongoRepository using quarkus ?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but you could do it something like this.

Define a repo

> this code is in kotkin

```
class YourRepositoryReactive : ReactivePanacheMongoRepository<YourEntity>{

fun getDomainDocuments():List<YourView>{
 
val aggregationPipeline = mutableListOf<Bson>()

// create your each stage with Document.parse("stage_obj") and add to aggregates collections

   return mongoCollection().aggregate(aggregationPipeline,YourView::class.java)
   }
```

mongoCollection() automatically executes on your Entity
YourView, a call to map related properties part of your output. Make sure that this class has

> @ProjectionFor(YourEntity.class)

annotation.

Hope this helps.